# What is the idiomatic way to write a linked list with a tail pointer?

Tags: linked-list, rust, reference-counting

As a learning project for Rust, I have a very simple (working, if incomplete) implementation of a singly linked list.  The declaration of the structs looks like this:

```
type NodePtr<T> = Option<Box<Node<T>>>;

struct Node<T> {
    data: T,
    next: NodePtr<T>,
}

pub struct LinkedList<T> {
    head: NodePtr<T>,
}
```

Implementing `size` and `push_front` were both reasonably straight-forward, although doing size iteratively did involve some "fighting with the borrow checker."

The next thing I wanted to try was adding a `tail` pointer to the `LinkedList` structure. to enable an efficient `push_back` operation.  Here I've run into a bit of a wall.  At first I attempted to use `Option<&Box<Node<T>>>` and then `Option<&Node<T>>`.  Both of those led to sprinkling `'a`s everywhere, but still eventually being unable to promise the lifetime checker that `tail` would be valid.

I have since come to the tentative conclusion that it is impossible with these definitions: that there is no way to *guarantee* to the compiler that `tail` would be valid in the places that I think it is valid.  The only way I can possibly accomplish this is to have all my pointers be `Rc<_>` or `Rc<RefCell<_>>`, because those are the only safe ways to have two things pointing at the same object (the final node).

My question: is this the correct conclusion?  More generally: what is the idiomatic Rust solution for unowned pointers inside data structures?  To my mind, reference counting seems awfully heavy-weight for something so simple, so I think I must be missing something.  (Or perhaps I just haven't gotten my mind into the right mindset for memory safety yet.)

Comment: You are correct; it is not possible to express cycles in safe Rust without shared ownership as provided by things like `Rc`.

Comment: This looks like the right answer to my question, but I don't really want shared ownership either.  I guess I'll do some playing around with `std::rc::Weak` in addition to `Rc`, since I just noticed the former exists.  Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: *To my mind, reference counting seems awfully heavy-weight for something so simple* => when you start opening your eyes to ownership issues (who is owning each piece of data), you will realize that your impression of simplicity is erroneous :)

Comment: Erroneous is a strong word; perhaps different?  It's a tricky statement because maintaining the invariants on a tail pointer in a singly linked list *is* very easy--it's a common high school CS topic.  Mathematically proving that they are maintained is a different issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, if you want to write a singly-linked-list with a tail-pointer you have three choices:

- Safe and Mutable: Use NodePtr = `Option<Rc<RefCell<Node<T>>>>`
- Safe and Immutable: Use NodePtr = `Option<Rc<Node<T>>>`
- Unsafe and Mutable: Use `tail: *mut Node<T>`

The `*mut` is going to be more efficient, and it's not like the `Rc` is actually going to *prevent* you from producing completely nonsense states (as you correctly deduced). It's just going to guarantee that they don't cause segfaults (and with RefCell it may still cause runtime crashes though...).

Ultimately, any linked list more complex than vanilla singly-linked has an ownership story that's too complex to encode in Rust's ownership system safely and efficiently (it's not a tree). I personally favour just embracing the unsafety at that point and leaning on unit tests to get to the finish-line in one piece (why write a suboptimal data structure...?).

Comment: This will surely sound like a leading question, but I assure you I am genuinely trying to understand the spirit of Rust.  If I am required to "embrace the unsafety" in order to write non-trivial, non-tree data structures, why wouldn't I just stick with C++, where I already have many years of experience?  Is the implication that most good data structures should be trees?  Or is there some other part of the story that I'm missing?

Comment: I would argue that writing collections is not something *most programs* will bother doing. They'll get their data structures pre-made (probably just from std). Collections are also fundamentally a low-level construct. You need to talk directly to the system allocator, work with partially initialized data, and maintain complex invariants. Especially if you want performance. Once you build your collection, it should expose an entirely safe interface, and no one needs to care about the insides. Rust also puts a bigger burden on fundamental libraries. Applications get a bigger win from safety.

Comment: As for most good data structures are trees: no, most good data structures are arrays. :)

Comment: On the note of "why not just C++": Rust's safety is modular and opt-out. For instance when you choose to work with uninitialized memory you don't suddenly have to worry about null pointers (also Safe Rust actually has really awesome 100% safe ways to work with uninitialized memory anyway). Also you spend anywhere from 100% to 90% of your time not worry about unsafety at all depending on the sort of code you're working on. C++? Unsafety is pervasive. 

( Just realized you might not get pinged on these responses, so cc @GrandOpener )